# Passing result from Swift Array to Segue to Description

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

Kind of new to Swift but enjoying the challenge so far. I have made some code but wondering how I can pass a selection from a firebase array in Swift to move the controller to a description? I've been the Code With Chris as a base but arrays are not covered in it.

Here is my code for the search array and segue. The array works fine but when a cell is selected, the segue occurs but no detail is brought up i.e. the text labels are empty.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code for the parsing the Firebase information into an Array

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class LocateTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet var locateTableView: UITableView!
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var firManager:FirebaseManager?
var placesArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filtersPlaces = [NSDictionary?]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search bars, brewpubs, shops..." 
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    // search based on name of place
    databaseRef.child("places").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.placesArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)
        // insert rows
        self.locateTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.placesArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filtersPlaces.count
    }
    return self.placesArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


    // Configure the cell...
    let place : NSDictionary?
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        place = filtersPlaces[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        place = self.placesArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = place?["type"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = place?["name"] as? String

    return cell
}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Check if there's a selection first
    if let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {

            // Get the selected place
            let selectedPlace = getPlaceForIndex(indexPath: actualIndexPath)

            // Create the detail model and set the place
            let detailModel = DetailModel()
            detailModel.place = selectedPlace

            // Set the detail model for the Detail View Controller
            let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            detailVC.model = detailModel

        }
    }
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
    // Update search results
}

func filterContent(searchText: String)
{
    self.filtersPlaces = self.placesArray.filter { place in
        let placename = place!["name"] as? String
        return(placename?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func getPlaceForIndex(indexPath:IndexPath) -> Place {
    return places[indexPath.row]
    }
```

}

And this is the code of the detail view controller that the information should be going into:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, DetailModelDelegate, WriteReviewChildViewControllerDelegate {

// MARK: - Properties

var place:Place?
var model:DetailModel?
var currentViewController:UIViewController?

@IBOutlet weak var placeImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var faveButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionSectionButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var reviewsSectionButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var writeReviewSectionButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!


@IBOutlet weak var viewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var viewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

// MARK: - View Controller Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register to listen for keyboard notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardIsShowing(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardIsHiding(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    // Check if there's a model
    // If so, then fetch the meta data for that place
    if let actualModel = model {

        // Set delegate to self
        actualModel.delegate = self

        // Call the get meta function
        actualModel.getMeta()

    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if let actualModel = model {
        actualModel.closeObserver()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Display

func displayMetaData() {

    // Check if there's a place object in the property
    if place == nil {
        return
    }

    // Set image
    model?.getImage(imageName: place!.detailImageName)

    // Set name label
    nameLabel.text = place!.name

    // Set the category label
    categoryLabel.text = place!.type

    // Set description
    if type(of: currentViewController!) == DescriptionChildViewController.self {
        (currentViewController as? DescriptionChildViewController)?.setDescriptionLabel(text: place!.desc)
    }


    else if type(of: currentViewController!) == ReviewsChildViewController.self {

        // In case the Reviews Child View Controller is already displayed,
        // We call this function to set the new data and refresh the table
        let reviewsVC = currentViewController as! ReviewsChildViewController
        reviewsVC.reloadReviewsData(newReviewData: place!.reviews)
    }

    // See if this place is faved
    setFaveButtonIcon()

}



// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Set the currentViewController property to the Description Child View Controller
    // because that's the first one that is shown in the container view
    currentViewController = segue.destination
}

@IBAction func sectionButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Declare a variable to hold the destination VC
    var toVC:UIViewController?

    // Set section button colors to white
    descriptionSectionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    reviewsSectionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    writeReviewSectionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)

    // Set active button color
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)

    // See which tag triggered this
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        // Description button tapped

        // Create an instance of the Description Child View Controller
        toVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DescriptionChildVC")

        if let descVC = toVC, let actualPlace = place {
            (descVC as! DescriptionChildViewController).descText = actualPlace.desc
        }

    case 2:
        // Reviews button tapped

        // Create an instance of the Description Child View Controller
        toVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReviewsChildVC")

        if let reviewsVC = toVC, let actualPlace = place {
            (reviewsVC as! ReviewsChildViewController).reviews = actualPlace.reviews
        }

    case 3:
        // Write a review button tapped

        // Create an instance of the Description Child View Controller
        toVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WriteReviewChildVC")

        if let writeReviewsVC = toVC {
            (writeReviewsVC as! WriteReviewChildViewController).delegate = self
        }

    default:
        // Description button tapped

        // Create an instance of the Description Child View Controller
        toVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DescriptionChildVC")
    }

    // Call SwitchChildViewControllers if currentViewController and toVC are not nil
    if let destinationVC = toVC, let currentVC = currentViewController {
        switchChildViewControllers(fromVC: currentVC, toVC: destinationVC)
    }

}

func switchChildViewControllers(fromVC:UIViewController, toVC:UIViewController) {

    // Tell the current VC that its transitioning
    fromVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    // Add the new VC
    self.addChildViewController(toVC)
    containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)

    // Size the frame of the toVC
    toVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds

    // Set the new VC alpha to 0
    toVC.view.alpha = 0

    // Animate the new VC alpha to 1 and the old VC alpha to 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

        toVC.view.alpha = 1
        fromVC.view.alpha = 0

    }) { (Bool) in

        // Remove the old VC
        fromVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        fromVC.removeFromParentViewController()

        // Tell the new VC that it has transitioned
        toVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        // Set the currentViewController property to toVC
        self.currentViewController = toVC

    }

}


// MARK: - Button Action Functions

@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Navigate back to the list
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func shareButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if place == nil {
        return
    }

    // Data items array
    var activityItems = [Any]()

    // Get the image
    let imageData = CacheManager.getImageFromCache(imageName: place!.detailImageName)

    if let actualImageData = imageData {

        // Since we have the image data, create a UIImage
        let image = UIImage(data: actualImageData)

        if image != nil {
            activityItems.append(image!)
        }
    }

    // Add the description to the activity items
    activityItems.append(place!.desc)

    // Create a UIActivityViewController
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    // Present it
    present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func routeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if place == nil {
        return
    }

    // Create a url
    let modifiedAddress = place!.addr.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?address=" + modifiedAddress)

    if let actualURL = url {


    // Open url
    UIApplication.shared.open(actualURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

}

@IBAction func favButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if place != nil {
        CacheManager.toggleFave(placeId: place!.id)
        setFaveButtonIcon()
    }

}

// MARK: - Helper Functions

func setFaveButtonIcon() {

    if CacheManager.isFave(placeId: place!.id) {
        faveButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark Ribbon Filled"), for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        faveButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark Ribbon"), for: .normal)
    }

}

// MARK: - DetailModelDelegate methods

func detailModel(metaDataFor place: Place) {

    // Set the place property
    self.place = place

    // Display the meta data in the views
    displayMetaData()

}

func detailModel(imageName: String, imageData: Data) {

    // Detail model has returned with image data
    // Now can set image view

    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

    if let actualImage = image {
        placeImageView.image = actualImage
    }
}

func detailModelSaveReviewError() {

    // Show the error alert

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There was an error saving your review", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func detailModelSaveReviewSuccess() {

    // Show the reviews child vc
    sectionButtonTapped(reviewsSectionButton)
}

// MARK: - WriteReviewChildViewControllerDelegate Methods

func saveReview(name: String, text: String) {

    // Child view controller is calling save review
    // Pass that data to the detail model
    if let actualModel = model {

        // Call saveReview of the detailmodel
        actualModel.saveReview(name, text)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardIsShowing(notification:NSNotification) {

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo

    if let userInfoDictionary = userInfo {

        let keyboardRect = userInfoDictionary["UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] as! CGRect

        // Animate the constraints
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {

            self.viewTopConstraint.constant = keyboardRect.height * -1
            self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardRect.height

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }
}

@objc func keyboardIsHiding(notification:NSNotification) {

    // Animate the constraints
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {

        self.viewTopConstraint.constant = 0
        self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = 0

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Call the "hide keyboard" function of the write reviews child view controller
    if type(of: currentViewController!) == WriteReviewChildViewController.self {
        (currentViewController as! WriteReviewChildViewController).hideKeyboard()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What's caused me headaches in the past.

1. Make sure outlet is properly connected. I've had to delete and reconnect.
2. Make sure cell style is set to detail.
3. Make sure cell identifier is set to "cell".

I've had to delete cell and recreate to resolve problems sometimes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - got the segue working still but now returns "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"